# Best way to create master page that has menu and links but displays main content from other pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a bunch of asp pages that I'm upgrading to asp.net. I'm trying to figure out a good way to achieve the following:

I basically wan't a portal page that has a menu bar and links to other sites in the company intranet but instead of redirecting to the other site when the link is clicked, it loads the page into the current one so that the links and menu bar are accessible to all of the other sites. My goal is to make it so that when a new website needs to be made, the developer can just add in the guts for the page, and add another link to the master page.

What would be a clean way to achieve this? Would it be best to have all of these (now separate) web applications bundled into one asp.net web application project, or is there an easy way to share a master page across many asp.net projects?

I'm new to asp.net and web development so any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: this can all be handled at the MasterPage level as well as coding the solution / fix in the IsPostBack conditional check as well.. sounds very simple.. also have you looked into doing siteMap along with using MasterPages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with **[ASP Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)**.

Although, if it is a possibility, I would jump into [ASPNET MVC framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc) and start using **[Razor Layouts](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx)**.

If you have the time, I believe it is worth it to jump into MVC, rather than basic ASP.NET.  MVC is an extension of ASP.NET and it will make your life much easier.  I have a master razor layout where I define every generic detail of the page I want to be across the site.

Hopefully those links might help.

---

EDIT: *Added Sample layout for Razor Layout in MVC 3.*

Here is a sample layout that I use for my projects that will hopefully give you a headstart with MVC if you decide to go that route.

```
@using System.Configuration
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <title>@(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Title) ? ViewBag.Title : ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationName"])</title>
    <meta name="description" content="@ViewBag.MetaDescription" />
    <meta name="robots" content="@ViewBag.Robots" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CDN-Scripts-Url"]/modernizr2.custom.01930.js"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @* ------------ CSS for Dropdown menu ----------------------
       Can be found in http://lwis.net/free-css-drop-down-menu/
       ---------------------------------------------------------
    *@
    <style type="text/css">
    /* Layout */
    @@import "@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CDN-Scripts-Url"]/free-css-drop-down-menu_v1.2/css/dropdown/dropdown.limited.css";
    /* Theme */
    @@import "@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CDN-Scripts-Url"]/free-css-drop-down-menu_v1.2/css/dropdown/themes/flickr.com/default.css";
    </style>
    <!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body { behavior:url("@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CDN-Scripts-Url"]/free-css-drop-down-menu_v1.2/js/csshover.htc"); }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
    @* ------------------------------------------------- *@
    <link href="@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CDN-Media-Url"]/Fonts/CopystructNormal/font-CopystructNormal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @RenderSection("Header", false)
    <!-- Change the UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID  -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleAnalyticsKey"]']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <nav>
                <div class="page ui-helper-clearfix">
                    <div id="logo">
                        <a href="@Url.Content("~/")">@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationName"]</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="mainMenu">
                    @RenderSection("MainMenu", false)
                    </div>

                    <div id="accountMenu" style="float:right">
                    @Html.Partial("_AccountMenuPartial")
                    </div>

                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="banner">
                <div class="page ui-helper-clearfix">
                    @RenderSection("Banner", false)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="page ui-helper-clearfix">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="push">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="page ui-helper-clearfix">
            Copyright 2012, @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CompanyName"]
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--! end of #container -->
    <!-- Javascript at the bottom for fast page loading -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Add all scripts here at the bottom of the page to avoid blocking page load.-->
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- scripts to support client side validation of forms -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CDN-Scripts-Url"]/topbar/topbar.js?v=1" type="text/javascript"></script>


    @RenderSection("Scripts", false)


    @* Google Analytics Async Script *@
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It might look a bit complex for someone who is not experienced with MVC.

Here are some links that inspired this template, or of the tools used in it.

- [Free CSS Menu](http://lwis.net/free-css-drop-down-menu/)
- [CSS Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)
- [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html): Which includes putting CSS at top, scripts at bottom, using a CDN for static files.
- [Google Analytics](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncTracking.html): tracking visits

I hope this helps a bit more and it is not overwhelming.

Comment: Thanks very much for the template and links

Answer (score 1):

Using frame or iframe is a way to load data from an external sources.